# Hibernate mapping accross tables (possible JOIN relationship)

Tags: java, hibernate

Can hibernate resolve mapping across more than one table.

Here is example:

- Class Manufacturer, table MANUFACTURER
- Class Car, table CAR Class
- CarType, table CAR_TYPE

ORM Model

- MANUFACTURER one to many CAR (MANUFACTURER_ID_FK in table CAR)
- CAR many to one CAR_TYPE (CAR_TYPE_ID_FK in table CAR)

What I want is hibernate mapping that will resolve all CAR TYPES for given Manufacturer?

So if I wanted to get all cars I would write

```
     <set name="cars" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
        <key property-ref="manufacturerIdFk">
            <column name="MANUFACTURER_ID_FK " precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="foo.bar.Car" />
    </set>
```

What I need is how to get car types for manufacturer?

```
<set name="carTypes" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
  ???
</set>
```

Thank you and please don't answer just get it from "cars" :) Solution what I would like to implement should completely really on hibernate mapping to do "heavy lifting". Thanks again.

Comment: "Solution what I would like to implement should completely really on hibernate mapping to do "heavy lifting"." there is a reason the common advice might be to add a `getAllCarTypes()` method to `Manufacturer` that loops through the `manufacturer.cars` list. Mapping the `carType` doubly might lead to errors on insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map directly manufacturer.carTypes collection as a ManyToMany relationship based on the association table : CAR.

Here is an example (Annotations) :
In class Manufacturer

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "CAR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MANUFACTURER_ID_FK"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CAR_TYPE_ID_FK"))
private Set<CarType> carTypes;
```

Comment: Thanks, I need XML mappings so I will try to re-write it in that way to try it out (this was just simplified problem). I am working on big project and afraid annotation mapping is not an option.

Comment: Try this one :
`<class name="Manufacturer">
    <set name="carTypes" inverse="true" table="CAR">
        <key column="MANUFACTURER_ID_FK"/>
        <many-to-many column="CAR_TYPE_ID_FK" class="CarType"/>
    </set>
</class>`

Comment: Unable to make it work like this, still investigating and reading trough book. I am afraid since I am in time crunch I will have to go with simpler solution just load for this example "Car" object and than extract what I need. Thanks for help, I will accept answer even if it didn't do the trick for me.